# drag and drop in selenium web driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried drag and drop with below code , but it is not working . can any one will help me.asap
I attached reference code in **screen shot**

[image]

Comment: Please add the code as a code block instead of as a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is performing the action after each step. Try performing it after you have defined all the actions:

```java
builder = new Actions(driver);

Action dragDrop = builder.clickAndHold(dragme)
    .moveToElement(dropme)
    .release(dropme)
    .build()
dragDrop.perform()
```

Comment: sorry I tried same thing but no working , can you plz suggest any another way

Comment: @rajeswari I'm gonna need to see your HTML if I want to be more specific. It's also a good idea to post your code in the question itself instead of adding it as a screenshot.

Comment: Hi,  I tried like these also but it is displaying error in "droppable" web element .                                                                                   WebElement dragme=driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]"));
   WebElement dropme=driver.findElement(By.id("droppable"));
   Actions builder = new Actions(driver); builder.dragAndDrop(dragme, dropme).perform();